# What does Gandalf imply?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-two-towers

In Two Towers, the following exchange takes place between Gandalf and Saruman:
[image]

[image]

**What does Gandalf want to imply ? Is there any reason for Saruman to not kill Theoden?**

Comment: You will not kill him.... **because I [Gandalf] will prevent you from doing so.**

Comment: What do you mean? Imply what? When? To whom? I don't understand this question at all…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Think of it this way:

"You failed to kill me, and you will fail to kill him because I will stop you"

This is what Gandalf is implying, not that Saruman has some sort of character flaw that prevents him from killing, it just means that he will be stopped before he can succeed.